# Search for help not working in Rstudio (?? Command)

Tags: r, rstudio

Rstudio search function is not working.

I tried `??tidyverse` and it returns "No Results Found" in the Help Windows.

[image: What I tried]

[image]
It should bring the help file describing the package or function asked.

My sessionInfo:
[image]

Comment: Indeed it doesn't work with any function

Comment: Press F1 on library(tidyverse)

Comment: Use one question mark: `?tidyverse`

Comment: Upvote because I’ve noticed the same recently